# How to join a data frame at the bottom of an existing one without rewriting the whole?

Tags: r, join, frames

```
df1 = data.frame(c(1,2),c(3,4))
colnames(df1) = c("V1","V2")

df2 = data.frame(c(2,3),c(5,6))
colnames(df2) = c("V1","V2")
```

How to add df2 at the bottom of df1 without using the rbind that requires the re writing of the entire dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do an assignment by creating a new row in 'df1' after extracting the first column of 'df2'

```
df1[nrow(df1)+1, ] <- df2[[1]]
df1
#  V1 V2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4
#3  2  3
```

NOTE: The OP showed a dataset 'df2' with a single column.  It is assumed that the number of rows in that column equals to the number of columns in 'df1'

---

With the new dataset, we can use

```
df1[nrow(df1) + seq_len(nrow(df2)),] <- df2
```

Comment: and what if df2 contains 2 rows?

Comment: @Simon You created `df2` with a single column 2  row dataset.  I showed the output  based on your input

Comment: @akun I will remove my answer based on the OP's updates and your improved answer.